# Purchased recycled ink. Now everything has a green tint

Tags: windows-10

I purchased recycled cartridges for my OfficeJet Pro and now everything is printed with a green tint. The magenta is not printing at all. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  In the future, please include as much pertinent information as you can, such as printer model, manufacturer of the dodgy ink cartridges, and any errors you've experienced since putting the new ink in.  It's purely speculation on my part, but it sounds like the magenta ink is not flowing - either stuck in the cartridge or gummed up further in the pipe.  My experience is that inkjet printers will error out rather than attempt to print if the ink doesn't reach the heads.

Answer (score 2):

Green tint may mean the black ink is smearing or some black ink was incorrectly put in the other colors.

You can try [the following](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/manually-clean-clogged-ink-cartridges-63631.html) to clean the cartridge and see if that helps.  If the cartridge wasn't used in a long time some of the ink may have dried in the nozzles.

If cleaning it does not resolve, you should return the cartridge and get your money back, and try a different cartridge.

If a new (not recycled) cartridge does the same thing, replace the printhead or entire printer.

Comment: These are new cartridges recently installed. As advised I cleaned the printhead 3 times and then aligned the printhead. After the second cleaning I finally got the magenta to print but the quality is not good. Three cleanings later the magenta still has a jagged edge. Thank you for the advice as I will be returning these and buying the manufacture's cartridges.

Answer (score 1):

Try a new set of Manufacturer's OEM cartridges and see if that fixes the printer. If not, you may be looking at new printer.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I hope I don't have to buy a new printer but...